# What is the Beta-Function used for in Calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

For a Calculus I course we have to learn about the Beta-function which is defined by $$B(q,p) = \int_0^1x^{p-1}(x-1)^{q-1}dx$$

What is the use/application for this? We are only given it as-is without any practical explanation.

Comment: It's used in differential equations and probability distributions.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=beta+function&oq=beta+functio